# How can I express a function of the minimized output of a function with two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, notation

I have a function

$$h(\theta, t)=\sqrt{(v\cos(\theta) - wR)^2t^2+(v\sin(\theta) t-R)^2}$$

in which $v$, $w$, $R$ are constants.

I am not sure how I can mathematically express minimizing this function with respect to $t$ for every values of $0<\theta<180$. In other words, I want to, for  instance, have $\theta$ to be 1 degree, and minimize it with respect to $t$ and obtain the $\operatorname{argmin} \,h(\theta =1, t)$. I then want to do this for $\theta = 2$, $\theta = 3$ ... $\theta = 179$. If possible, I would like to express all the values of $\operatorname{argmin} \,h(\theta, t)$ for each $\theta$. Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Try to minimize the square. It is simple

Comment: Hi there, I understand how to minimize the function but I was just wondering how I can mathematically express minimizing the function with respect t for all values of $\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for a function of the single variable $\theta$ (angular degree) as in:

> Let $g$ be
> \begin{align*}
> &g:(0,180)\to \mathbb{R}\\
> &g(\theta)=\min_{t\in\mathbb{R}} h(\theta,t)
> \end{align*}

Comment: Hi!  That is exactly what I am looking for! Sorry, would "min" be "argmin"

Comment: @StevenOh: You're welcome! The term $\min$ is correct in this context. We do not need any additional specification as we have a function $g$ with one variable only.

Comment: Thank you so much!